# SQL Query - Get Subquery results in Rows rather then Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery

I checked the Search, but none seem to answer this Question.. I expect it to be farely simple though:
I have a query that results in two columns, but I need it to result in two rows.. Anyone know how?

this is the query:

```
               SELECT        (SELECT        COUNT(Id) AS Expr1
                      FROM            Table
                      WHERE        (Description LIKE 'door%')) AS Door,
                         (SELECT        COUNT(Id) AS Expr1
                           FROM            Table AS Table_1
                           WHERE        (Description LIKE 'window%')) AS Window
```

The result I GET is (of course):

```
[Door]     [Window]
56         34
```

The result I'd LIKE to have is the following:

```
[OPTION]    [NROfRecords]
Door        56
Window      34
```

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 'Door'   AS Option, COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE description LIKE 'door%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Window' AS Option, COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE description LIKE 'window%'
```

OR...

```
WITH
  filtered AS
(
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN description LIKE 'door%'   THEN 'Door'
         WHEN description LIKE 'window%' THEN 'Window'
                                         ELSE 'Other' END AS option,
    *
  FROM
    yourTable
  WHERE
       description LIKE 'door%'
    OR description LIKE 'window%'
)
SELECT
  option,
  COUNT(id)
FROM
  filtered
GROUP BY
  option
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  lookup.option,
  COUNT(id)
FROM
(
  SELECT 'door'   AS option
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'window' AS option
)
  AS lookup
INNER JOIN
  yourTable
    ON yourTable.description LIKE lookup.option + '%'
GROUP BY
  lookup.option
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), I would advise rewriting the query though to below:

```
select *
from
(
  SELECT 
    sum(case when Description LIKE 'door%' then 1 else 0 end) Door,
    sum(case when Description LIKE 'window%' then 1 else 0 end) Window
  from Table1
) x
unpivot
(
  NrOfRecords
  for [Option] in (Door,  Window)
) u
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a577d/3)

Comment: Unpivot from a resultset that comes from data already in rows? That seems rather longwinded

Comment: Yes, I think unpivot solution is way to complicated for that task

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    case when description like 'door%' then 'door'
         when description like 'window%' then 'window' 
         else '' 
    end as [desc],
    count(id)
from table
where description like 'door%' or description like 'window%'
group by 
(
    case when description like 'door%' then 'door'
    when description like 'window%' then 'window' else '' end
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution like this is following DRY principle - you do not repeat Door or Window anywhere.
It also easy to add another entities here, so you do not repeat a logic.

```
select
    C.description,
    count(*)
from Table1 as t
    inner join (
        select 'door%', 'Door' union all
        select 'window%', 'Window'
    ) as C(pattern, description) on t.description like c.pattern
group by C.description
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a577d/14)</kbd>**

Comment: You still need a small element of repeating yourself; in the `WHERE` clause to only get the `door` and `window` data.  You could filter by the derived `type_name` but that would obfuscate indexes and damage performance to gain marginal maintainability.  *[I did **not** down vote this, I love `CROSS APPLY`.   I disagree with the down-vote.]*

Comment: Hi Roman, Thanks! seems to work, however it does return this 'error':
The OUTER APPLY SQL construct or statement is not supported.
I'm using SQL server 2008

Comment: yes if you have other options you need to add
where Description LIKE 'door%' or Description LIKE 'window%' but anyway this solution is very comfortable to read for me, so I'm using it very often

Comment: well I've never seen that error before :)
I did some search, do you trying to make a view with that query?

Comment: BTW, solution will work if you write CROSS APPLY instead of OUTER APPLY, and you'll not need to write Description like '%'. I'm not sure about indexes, it's better to check on real data